# How To Reverse Bevel A Cylinder Made With Screw Modifier

Tags: modifiers, bevel, screw-modifier

In my projects I want to be as non-destructively as possible. For that reason I create all cylinders using the screw modifier. Like described in  [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XNVyQpH_Uk0) you can invert the normals of the top face of a cylinder and create reverse bevels.

Since I'm using the screw modifier to create the cylinder, I'm not able to flip the normals of the top face since it is actually not there yet, the only thing I have are the edges which form the cylinder using the screw modifier.

[image]

So I'm stuck, I cannot reverse this bevel, no matter what I try..

How can I create a reverse bevel on a cylinder that is made from a screw modifier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can skip the bevel altogether and build the bevel into the profile that you're turning:

[image: bevel via profile change]

Comment: This seems to be only way to easily achieve the reversed bevel. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Custom Profile - you can control the resolution with the number of bevel steps.

[image: Bev]

Comment: While interesting shapes can be achieved like that. Creating a reversed bevel is a little tedious. So I think it's not best suited for the job. Thanks anyway, was a great tip.

Comment: Yeah... I wan't entirely sure what you meant by "reversed bevel", so I took a guess - It seems you mean you want the top part outwards? In that case, you are correct, this would not be the best method for that. I'll leave this answer up anyways in case people are looking for the "other definition" of reversed bevel - a lot of people miss the custom profile because it's hidden under a drop menu.